# How to enable text selection only on one span?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a webpage with shell commands. They are displayed like `$ ls -la`. I would like to be able to double click on the line and select only the command, not the `$` and the space.

I was able to not do the select `$` but I still have the white space selected. What will be the best strategy to do it?

Here is a codepen with the example https://codepen.io/benoit_tgt/pen/OJMMgRQ

Behind I am using [PrismJS](https://prismjs.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```css
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
```

I was able to remove the space. See: https://codepen.io/benoit_tgt/pen/OJMMgRQ